# Getting empty(blank) value while printing JSON field (value) using JsonConverter.Deserialize in C#

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

I am trying to parse a JSON using NewtonSoft (my JSON is an array type). Below is what it looks like...

```
{
  "steps": [
    {
      "stepsType": "runWizard",
      "wizardType": "demoServer",
      "config": {
        "mode": "add",
        "resourceName": "demo server 1",
        "activeDbPrimaryServer": {
          "serverName": "abc",
          "serverAddress": "abc.demo.local"
        },
        "activeDbCatalog": "demoActiveDB",
        "activeDBUserId": "sa",
        "activeDBPassword": "xyz",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have created a class using JsonToC# convertor....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ServerSetupWizardConsoleApp
{
    // Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 
    public class ActiveDbPrimaryServer
    {
        public string serverName { get; set; }
        public string serverAddress { get; set; }
    }

    public class Config
    {
        public string mode { get; set; }
        public string resourceName { get; set; }
        public ActiveDbPrimaryServer activeDbPrimaryServer { get; set; }
        public string activeDbCatalog { get; set; }
        public string activeDBUserId { get; set; }
        public string activeDBPassword { get; set; }
    }

    public class Step
    {
        public string stepsType { get; set; }
        public string wizardType { get; set; }
        public Config config { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public List<Step> steps { get; set; }
    }    
}
```

And now when I am trying to deserialise it in another class, I am getting a empty response in console...
I have a **TEXT** from where I am reading the JSON and then storing it in a string type variable and the using the string to deserialise it.

```
public Object ReadJson()
        {
            string jsonText = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Desktop\\demo.json");

            var rootObject = (Root) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonText, typeof(Root));

            var activeDbAttr = (ActiveDbPrimaryServer)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonText, typeof(ActiveDbPrimaryServer));

            Console.WriteLine("Value : " + activeDbAttr.serverAddress);

        }
```

This **activeDbAttr.serverAddress** is giving me nothing in **CONSOLE**

It print --> value : (nothing after ":" like blank)

Can someone tell me what is wrong here. I followed some old answers, not getting to a point where I can fix it.

Comment: Somewhat makes sense - the code shown seem to be reading `Root` object (which matches JSON shown) and then discard the result and tries to read the same JSON as `ActiveDbPrimaryServer` which indeed will not find any matching fields... Could you please check if code matches the JSON? So far looks like "typo"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live demo : https://dotnetfiddle.net/PuO8F8

#### It's a simple navigation issue.

You deserialize to a Root object, and instead of navigating with the property you deserialize again into an other thing, hopping to land in the right place.

```
var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonText);
var activesDBs = json.steps.Select( x=> x.config.activeDbPrimaryServer).ToList();
```

Result:

```
Dumping object(System.Linq.SelectListIterator`2[Step,ActiveDbPrimaryServer])
[
   {
   serverAddress  : abc.demo.local
   serverName     : abc
   }
]
```

#### Why did it failed ?

```
var jsonDB = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ActiveDbPrimaryServer>(GetJson());
```

Tell the Parser that the Json is of type `ActiveDbPrimaryServer`.
The parser open the Json and find the first object:

```
{
  "steps": [..]
}
```

Look for the property of the expected type `ActiveDbPrimaryServer`

```
public class ActiveDbPrimaryServer
{
    public string serverName { get; set; }
    public string serverAddress { get; set; }
}
```

And find nothing. It end there and give you an object of the right type with no property initialized

#### Partial deserialization:

If you want to deserialize only the part you need, refer to this documentation from Newtonsoft:
[Deserializing Partial JSON Fragments](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm)

```
JObject rootObj = JObject.Parse(GetJson());
// get JSON result objects into a list
IList<JToken> results = rootObj["steps"].Children() // Step is a list so we use `.Children()` 
                               ["config"]["activeDbPrimaryServer"].ToList();

IList<ActiveDbPrimaryServer> dbResults = new List<ActiveDbPrimaryServer>();
foreach (JToken result in results)
{
    // JToken.ToObject is a helper method that uses JsonSerializer internally
    ActiveDbPrimaryServer dbResult = result.ToObject<ActiveDbPrimaryServer>();
    dbResults.Add(dbResult);
}
```

Comment: I tried your approach, "var activesDBs = json.steps.Select( x=> x.config.activeDbPrimaryServer).ToList();"   for this I am getting --> Value : System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] when I am trying to Console.WriteLine("Value : " + activesDBs);

Comment: `ToList`.. It's a list .. If you print a list  you get the list name. `System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String]` means I'm a Generic.List.
It's a List because there can be multiple steps. You still fail on simple object navigation.

Comment: Update the demo https://dotnetfiddle.net/PuO8F8. Btw the **`[System.String]`** in your previous comment mean that you modify the property type to string ... Chaging to `public string activeDbPrimaryServer { get; set; }` and that make no sense.

Answer (score 0):

you are deserializing

```
var rootObject = (Root) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonText, typeof(Root));
var activeDbAttr = (ActiveDbPrimaryServer)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonText, typeof(ActiveDbPrimaryServer));
```

[the second one yields `null` ... and null cast to `ActiveDbPrimaryServer` yields `null`.]

the same string twice into 2 different types of objects that do not share common base class (of course other than object).

your text represents either a Root or a ActiveDbPrimaryServer not both. the ActiveDbPrimaryServer is a member of the config class  and that in turn of Step. ....

step through your graph root.Step.Config .. if all the instances are set you should reach your instance of ActibeDdPrimaryServer

Comment: from text you mean jsonText?

Comment: I removed "var activeDbAttr" and I tried to use "var rootObject" to walk through the graph but when I did this "Console.WriteLine("Value : " + rootObject.steps.config.activeDbPrimaryServer)  --> I am getting Lis<Step> does not contain definition for config

Comment: yes, your jsonText is a string...it represents an instance of an object. you can deserialize only to the type that it represents (and cast to a  base type later)